# Row element unallowed in android manifest

Tags: android

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTeHY.jpg) Row element and key element unallowed in android manifest

The app runs perfect but i can see no keyboard being displayed in my AVD, it throws the message you can see in the picture within the link "My code". I'm new in android and trying to create a simple keyboard, any help will be useful, thanks so much.

`````
     <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:keyWidth="10%p"
        android:horizontalGap="3dp"
        android:verticalGap="3dp"
        android:keyHeight="60dp"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
        <Row>
            <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
            <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
            <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
            <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
            <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
            <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
            <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
            <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
            <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
            <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0"/>
            <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
            <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
            <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
            <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
            <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
            <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
            <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
            <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
            <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
            <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
            <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
            <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
            <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
            <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
            <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
            <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
            <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
            <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
            <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="CAPS" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
            <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
            <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
            <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
            <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
            <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
            <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
            <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
            <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
            <Key android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyLabel="\? ! :"   android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        </Row>
        <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
            <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
            <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
            <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="60%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
            <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimary" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
        </Row>
 </Keyboard>````
`````

Comment: Where is the picture and error log?

Comment: I edited, sorry, i'm new here! you can see the picture in the link "My code", just refresh the page, thanks!

Comment: Please add the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: There it is, i edited de question